# Tailwindcss use hover over group-hover

Tags: tailwind-css

I added a group hover to an element but also a hover to that element. The group-hover works, but when I hover over the element itself the background color doesn't change.

```
bg-green-500 group-hover:bg-green-200 hover:bg-green-500
```

Comment: Doesnt look like this is possible to do. The `group` hover will take precedence over the elements hover.

Answer (score 12):

This is now possible with [Tailwind Just-in-Time mode](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode), using the [built-in important modifier](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode#built-in-important-modifier):

```
<div className="group">
  <div className="opacity-0 group-hover:opacity-50 hover:!opacity-100">
    Note the magic of the exclamation point!
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Double up on selectors (`group-hover:hover:...`):

`bg-green-500 group-hover:bg-green-200 group-hover:hover:bg-green-500`

Answer (score -1):

u need to add 'group' class to your parent element like this:

```
<div class="group">
   <div class="bg-green-500 group-hover:bg-green-200 hover:bg-green-500">
      <div class="hover:bg-green-500">
      CONTENT 1
      </div>
      <div>
      CONTENT 2
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

it change background to green-200 when you hover group element and its children like Content 2 above, and also change background to green-500 when you hover the content 1

hope it works :)

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. You need the ! important in order for the style to be applied.